# Paused and play time interval slider in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, setinterval, use-effect

I am create a slider worked with time interval and i add extra feature Pause and Play , code ..

```
const [value, setValue] = useState('1')
  const [status, setStatus] = useState("working");
  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
   
        console.log(status);
        if (status === "working") {
            const interval = setInterval(() => {
                if(parseInt(value) + 1 === 3) {
                    setValue('1')
                } else {
                    setValue((parseInt(value) + 1).toString())
                }
                document.getElementById('slide' + value).click()
             }, 5000)
            return () => clearInterval(interval)
        }else if(status === "paused"){
            
        }
       
   
  })
  
  const puseSlide = () => {
    setStatus("paused");
  }

return(

<div>
 {value === '1' && (
  <img src={Imageone}/>
 )}
 {value === '2' && (
  <img src={Imagetwo}/>
 )}
 
 <Tabs value={value} onChange={handleChange}>
    <Tab onClick={puseSlide} id="slide1" value="1">.</Tab>
    <Tab onClick={puseSlide} id="slide2" value="1">.</Tab>
 </Tabs>
</div>

)
```

This slider is working but i am writing onclick event that automatically called first slide change, Why? i am new in react

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> document.getElementById('slide' + value).click()

This line in `useEffect` is the cause of the issue. After incrementing the value you are performing a click action on the element with id "slide" or "slide2" which is invoking the function `puseSlide`. You'd instead want to pause only when the user explicitly clicks on the pause button. To avoid calling the `puseSlide` function simply remove this line `document.getElementById('slide' + value).click()` from `useEffect` hook and you should not observe the function being called after the first slide changes.

Comment: that issue is solved how we do for play again the slider

Comment: You can have another button clicking on which the status is changed to `working`. E.g: `<Tab onClick={()=>setStatus('working')}>Play</Tab>`